# Issue with rendering view page in node express.js application

Tags: html, node.js, express

I am trying to render a static HTML page located in the `views` directory but when I try to visit that route, the Node.js console firing an error.

Error message

```
TypeError: path must be absolute or specify root to res.sendFile
    at ServerResponse.sendFile (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\node-mvc-setup\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:425:11)
    at C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\node-mvc-setup\app.js:21:7
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\node-mvc-setup\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\node-mvc-setup\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\node-mvc-setup\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\node-mvc-setup\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\node-mvc-setup\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\node-mvc-setup\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\node-mvc-setup\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at urlencodedParser (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\node-mvc-setup\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\urlencoded.js:91:7)
```

Index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Test Node MVC Front Page</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Great index font page</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

Index route

```js
const express = require("express");

//require the express router

const router = express.Router();

router.get("/", function(req, res, next) {
  res.sendFile("/views/index.html");
});

module.exports = router;
```

[image: Image of Project structure]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you require `path` module in your code and try doing this instead:

```js
router.get("/", function(req, res, next) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../views', 'index.html'));
});
```

Comment: Thanks @nishkaush for the head up.

For those in my shoe, see the correct route code below

Answer (score 0):

```
//require path
```

const path = require('path');

//require express
const express = require("express");

//require express router

const router = express.Router();

router.get("/", function(req, res, next) {

```
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../', 'views', 'index.html'));
```

});

module.exports = router